# IntelliJ: setting AWS env vars for gradle run config

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, amazon-s3, intellij-idea, amazon-iam

I'm trying to set up my local dev env for a Java Spring Boot configured with gradle which needs a working AWS CLI environment. It's important to note that there are different profiles (`.aws/config`) present (`default` not configured) which are different role switches (`role_arn`) with MFA (`mfa_serial`).

---

### Description

At the moment I'm using Windows 10 Build 18363 ("19.09"), IntelliJ Ultimate 20.02, gradle 5.6.4.
In order to run this application I've set up a run configuration with the gradle `clean bootRun` task and the following env vars:

- `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`
- `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`
- `AWS_REGION`
- `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`
- `AWS_PROFILE`
- `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE`

```
#.aws/config
[profile prod]
region=eu-central-1
output=json
role_arn=<role_arn_prod>
source_profile=site-iam
mfa_serial=<arn_iam_user_mfa_1>


[profile sit]
region=eu-central-1
output=json
role_arn=<role_arn_sit>
source_profile=site-iam
mfa_serial=<arn_iam_user_mfa_1>

[profile dev]
region=eu-central-1
output=json
role_arn=<role_arn_dev>
source_profile=site-iam
mfa_serial=<arn_iam_user_mfa_1>

[profile site-iam]
region=eu-central-1
output=json

[default]
```

```
#.aws/credentials
[default]
aws_access_key_id = <access_key_id_1>
aws_secret_access_key = <secret_access_key_1>

[site-iam]
aws_access_key_id = <access_key_id_1>
aws_secret_access_key = <secret_access_key_1>
```

---

### Behaviour

The request inside of this java application is quite simple.

```java
GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
    .bucket(this.bucket)
    .key(this.key)
    .build();
String response = this
    .s3Client
    .getObjectAsBytes(getObjectRequest).asString(Charset.forName(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
```

The error below suggests that there was no role switch and / or the authentication failed (because we need to submit the TOTP in order to authenticate.

```
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: Access Denied (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: <REQUEST_ID>)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleErrorResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:123) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:79) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handle(CombinedResponseHandler.java:59) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handle(CombinedResponseHandler.java:40) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:40) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:30) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:73) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:77) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:39) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:64) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:34) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:56) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:36) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:189) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:121) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.doExecute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:147) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:76) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:52) ~[sdk-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:62) ~[aws-core-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.getObject(DefaultS3Client.java:3606) ~[s3-2.13.13.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client.getObjectAsBytes(S3Client.java:7563) ~[s3-2.13.13.jar:na]
```

A similar behaviour is reproduciblevia the cmd

```
aws s3 ls

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied
```

---

### Different approaches

#### STS get-session-token | env var

I've obtained the session token  via

```sh
aws sts get-session-token --serial <arn_iam_user_mfa_1> --token-code <TOTP> --duration-seconds 129600
```

as json

```
{
    "Credentials": {
        "AccessKeyId": "<access_key_id_2>",
        "SecretAccessKey": "<secret_access_key_2>",
        "SessionToken": "<session_token_2>",
        "Expiration": "2020-08-02T22:57:12+00:00"
    }
}
```

and set updated the following env vars to the obtained values:

- `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`: `<access_key_id_2>`
- `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`: `<secret_access_key_2>`
- `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`: `<session_token_2>`
- `AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN`: `<session_token_2>`

but this is returning the same error

```
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: Access Denied (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: <request_id>)
```

---

#### Quick and dirty `.aws/config` fix

After several time of debugging the `default` profile was changed in the following way

```
[default]
region=eu-central-1
output=json
role_arn=<role_arn_prod>
source_profile=site-iam
mfa_serial=<arn_iam_user_mfa_1>
```

which resulted in

```
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from any of the providers in the chain AwsCredentialsProviderChain(credentialsProviders=[SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider(), EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider(), ProfileCredentialsProvider(), ContainerCredentialsProvider(), InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider()]) : [SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider(): Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId)., EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(): Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId)., WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider(): Either the environment variable AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE or the javaproperty aws.webIdentityTokenFile must be set., ProfileCredentialsProvider(): To use assumed roles in the '<ROLE_PROFILE>' profile, the 'sts' service module must be on the class path., ContainerCredentialsProvider(): Cannot fetch credentials from container - neither AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_FULL_URI or AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI environment variables are set., InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(): Unable to load credentials from service endpoint.]
```

---

#### Setting `AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE`

The `AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE` env var was set to an existing token file located in `~/.aws/cli/cache` via a WSL sytle path (`\wsl$\...`)
which leads to the same error as above even though the the env vars are present and / or updated

```
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from any of the providers in the chain AwsCredentialsProviderChain(credentialsProviders=[SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider(), EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider(), ProfileCredentialsProvider(), ContainerCredentialsProvider(), InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider()]) : [SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider(): Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId)., EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(): Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId)., WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider(): Either the environment variable AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE or the javaproperty aws.webIdentityTokenFile must be set., ProfileCredentialsProvider(): To use assumed roles in the '<ROLE_PROFILE>' profile, the 'sts' service module must be on the class path., ContainerCredentialsProvider(): Cannot fetch credentials from container - neither AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_FULL_URI or AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI environment variables are set., InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(): Unable to load credentials from service endpoint.]
```

---

### Debugging

There are no permission problems.
The download of this specific file works with the correct role arn.

```
C:\Users\tunnelblick>aws s3 ls

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied

C:\Users\tunnelblick>aws s3 ls --profile prod
Enter MFA code for <arn_iam_user_mfa_1>:
2020-02-05 09:28:41 <bucket_1>
2020-06-23 05:16:07 <bucket_2>

C:\Users\tunnelblick>aws s3 cp s3://<bucket_1>/<file>.json .
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

C:\Users\tunnelblick>aws s3 cp s3://<bucket_1>/<file>.json . --profile prod
download: s3://<bucket_1>/<file>.json to .\<file>.json
```

Setting these env vars in my WSL 1 terminal and executing `aws s3 ls` resulted in the same `Access Denied` error
(`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied`)

Comment: Do you use Gradle run configuration? Please note that in Gradle configuration you specify the options and environment variables to the process which runs the Gradle task, not the process which is launched by this task. To pass the option to the application you should specify the options in build.gradle file as you would configure it if started the application from command line by Gradle task. If you want to specify Spring boot profile, please check https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006978240/comments/360001367859

Comment: The spring boot profile is not the problem and I‘m aware how to set it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Andrey I may try to change my project setup in order to pass jvm arguments. Let's see.

Comment: @Andrey the JVM args didn't solve the problem but I could luckily find a solution to this problem. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later on I also tried to set these values in the `~/.aws/credentials` file. It seems that I was missing some options which could be solved with [aws-mfa](https://github.com/broamski/aws-mfa) (a python wrapper for AWS STS).
I was using the following [example](https://github.com/broamski/aws-mfa#Usage)

```
aws-mfa --duration 1800 --device arn:aws:iam::123456788990:mfa/dudeman --assume-role arn:aws:iam::123456788990:role/some-role --role-session-name some-role-session`
```

This populates the `default` profile with additional options for a proper role switching like `assumed_role`, `assume_role_arn`, `aws_session_token`, `aws_security_token`, `expiration` and works like a charm with my run config.